# Why does Todoroki look different between the 1st and 2nd season?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In season 1 of *My Hero Academia*, Todoroki looks like this:

[image: Season 1; Todoroki appearance]

In season 2, he looks like this:

[image: Season 2; Todoroki appearance]

As can be seen from the first image, his *left* side (and *not* his right side) is his ice side. His left eye is also round and red. I believe there is only 1 short instance in season 2 when he activates his fire power where his left eye becomes round and red.

Another difference is that in season 1, Todoroki's left side is always encased in ice, but never in season 2. Even when he uses his ice Quirk extensively in season 2, he is only seen with a little ice on himself:

[image: Season 2 Todoroki 2]

What is the reason for the difference between season 1's and season 2's Todoroki?

Comment: even when his left looks like covered in ice his left side is always his burning side, and his right side freeze. at least that's how it goes in manga

Comment: @Darjeeling it might be that way in the anime too. I just assumed because his left side was encased in ice it was his ice side.

Comment: Even if his left side was covered in ice, it's still the fire side. You can check the colour of his hair. It's white on the right side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first picture, it was Todoroki wearing his hero costume. In episode 6 to 8, they had mock battles wearing their costumes. It is also explained that the students can give their own design for their costume.

The second one, it's in the Sports Festival where they cannot wear hero costumes because they will have an advantage to their enemies.

---

Regarding freezing and shivering, if you're referring in the 1st picture, no, he won't freeze because that is just his hero costume, not his quirk at work.

But if you're talking about his quirk, then the answer is still no, because he uses the other half of his quirk which is

> half hot

to keep himself from the effects of his half cold and vice versa.

Comment: So why doesn't he freeze from freezing his left side? Why does he shiver when using his power in the Sports Festival?

Comment: If this is correct and the ice over his left side is his costume, then that is massive foreshadowing of his disdain for his father and his fire powers.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

The ice on his side from season one is actually a part of his costume. It's possible to tell because he never wanted to use his flames, so he covered the side in ice so that no one would see his father's quirk in him.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! The first picture was Todoroki in his hero costume. **His left side was most likely encased in ice because he didn't want to show it** (after all, he hates his father and vowed to himself to never use flames.) In the UA Sports Festival, however, they cannot wear their hero suits. Like the first answer said, the use of hero suits would be an unfair advantage (for example, Katsuki Bakugo can make massive explosions with his hand grenades, which would totally change things up.) I really like Todoroki's character! I hope this cleared things up so you can enjoy and understand him better too! ^^