# Why did they change Todoroki's hero suit?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So in the first season, this was Shoto's hero suit.

[image]

And I think sometime in the third season, it changed.

[image]

Now, I really like his suit. Don't get me wrong but, why did it change all of a sudden?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Todoroki look different between the 1st and 2nd season?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43355/why-does-todoroki-look-different-between-the-1st-and-2nd-season)

Answer (score 1):

> In his initial hero costume …. has what appears to be a material resembling ice covering his whole left side, even his head, although it is detachable, which he wears as a way of rejecting the fire aspect of his Quirk.
>
> <sub>[Source](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Shoto_Todoroki)</sub>

Early on in the series, Todoroki rejected his fire side of his quirk as a way of rejecting his father; where his fire quirk originated from. His original costume design covers his whole left side with ice-looking apparel, which is the side of his fire quirk. This resembles his choice of using his ice quirk.

After Todoroki comes to accept who he is and both of side of his quirks, he upgrades the design of his hero costume so that both sides of his quirk is represented.